# "to apply a distancing objectivity"

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does "to apply a distancing objectivity" mean?

Context:

It is an unsettling experience but at the same time the participant cannot help but apply a distancing objectivity to monitor its effectiveness and ponder where she really is in time and place

Comment: It means that the writer is full of himself.  But he's presumably attempting to convey that by forcing a sort of "objectivity" ("distancing oneself" from the matter of consideration) the "participant" can somehow improve his or her ability to  evaluate the situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the participant is going to monitor an experiment.  An unbiased observation of what is going on requires a certain distancing from it. If you are not distant enough - e.g. you are doing it, so you're not distant enough - some subjectivity may be involved and individual bias may eventually go unnoticed.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but really that's all anyone can do -- guess.  This is part of 131336's ongoing attempt to under *Art and Science*, Sian Ede's work in "cultural" studies.  But if Ede's words have any definitive meaning, they are private to her mind.

Answer (score 1):

The quotation is another contribution of the grandiloquent Siân Ede to the befogged modern mind. This one comes from [*Art and Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5_jVBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT128&dq=%22the+ominous,+now+of+the+ridiculous%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIjoSAtKuLyQIVFthjCh0kxAkf#v=onepage&q=%22the%20ominous%2C%20now%20of%20the%20ridiculous%22&f=false) (2005). Here, for context, is the complete paragraph in which it appears:

> The Canadian artists Janet Cardiff and George Bures Miller create what they call 'aural hallucinations'. In *The Missing Voice (Case Study B)*, the participant takes a walk around East London, wearing headphones which provide convincing 3D sound. The soundtrack is a disjointed narrative created by a stream of interrupted consciousness which cuts in and out, weaving medieval plainsong into the dark narratives of pulp fiction and film noir, to eighteenth-century historical reference, now charged with a sense of the ominous, now of the ridiculous. **It is an unsettling experience but at the same time the participant cannot help but apply a distancing objectivity to monitor its effectiveness and ponder where she really is in time and place**, pursuing an internal reverie, partly imposed, partly her own, while interacting with the real world out there.

The sense of "distancing objectivity" is that rather than simply being assaulted by the prerecorded 3D sounds of *The Missing Voice (Case Study B)*, the person wearing the headphones adopts an ongoing role as a critical judge of the effectiveness of the performance as well as being a participant in it. It's as if a laboratory rat were not merely reacting to an experimental drug it has ingested, but also assessing the technical rigorousness of the experiment itself.

Judging something critically requires having some degree of separation (or distance) from the thing being judged, so that the judgment isn't a purely visceral or emotional response; and reaching an intellectually satisfying conclusion requires presenting an argument that at least seems to employ a fair-minded analytical approach (or objectivity). Combine those ideas, and you get a fair-minded analytical approach that yields some degree of separation of the judge from the thing being judged—or in short, "distancing objectivity."